# ASP.net Session Management for multiple users

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net Website deployed in IIS. Used windows authentication. When multiple users are accessing the site the session is stored  for the first user.If people are accessing only one after other no problrm but for concurrent users it shows problem. How to handle session in webconfig ya session variabe? i am using session[id]=txtuser.text for maintaining the current session? do i have to do more than this?

Comment: What do you mean by _the session is violated_ and _webconfig session variable_? Are you running on a single server, or multiple load-balanced servers? If you could _edit_ your question to include more information, we may be able to help.

Comment: Need to explain what do you mean by session is voilated as IIS automatically manages every concurrent session individually.
if 100 users are logged in that means IIS is maintaining 100 sessions.

Comment: Ok. i mean to say i have done the deployment on iis of server . if multiple users are accessing the website it is taking the id of first user who is logged in to the web.